# Re-registering signal handler causes infinite loop

Tags: c, signals, posix, infinite-loop, sigint

With the following signal handler, pressing `Ctrl-C` causes the handler to be called repetitively, and I don't know why:

(Warning: if you type `Ctrl-C`, you'll have to use `kill <pid>` to exit the program)

```
static void handler(int sig) {
        // do something interesting

        // write so I can see if I'm in an infinite loop
        write(1, "A", 1);

        // raise normal signal behavior
        // this ensures normal signal behavior
        // for example, exiting with code 130 if Ctrl-C is used
        signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
        raise(sig);

        // re-register handler
        // that way, if signal doesn't exit the program and the signal
        //   is sent again in the future, this handler will run again
        signal(sig, handler);
}
```

So I know that I don't understand something about signal handlers. I **assumed** that only `SIGCONT` would ever make it to the last line, because `SIGINT` (for example), when it is raised with the default behavior (`SIG_DFL`) should exit and not return.

I also know I could wrap the last line in an if statement that only does it for `SIGCONT`, but I really want to know why it isn't behaving the way I expect.

## Question(s)

1. Why does the signal handler get called in an infinite loop?
2. How can I have a handler that does something interesting, calls the default behavior, and then re-registers itself in case the default behavior doesn't exit the program?

## MCVE

This can be run by writing it to a file `sigtest.c` and doing `make sigtest`. Use `Ctrl-C` to raise `SIGINT`, and in another terminal, be prepared to do `ps | grep sigtest` and then `kill <pid>`.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void handler(int sig) {
        // do something interesting

        // write so I can see if I'm in an infinite loop
        write(1, "A", 1);

        // raise normal signal behavior
        // this ensures normal signal behavior
        // for example, exiting with code 130 if Ctrl-C is used
        signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
        raise(sig);

        // re-register handler
        // that way, if signal doesn't exit the program and the signal
        //   is sent again in the future, this handler will run again
        signal(sig, handler);
}

int main(void) {
        char c;
        signal(SIGINT, handler);
        signal(SIGTSTP, handler);
        signal(SIGCONT, handler);
        printf("type 'x' and 'Enter' to exit\n");
        while (1) {
                c = getchar();
                printf("got char: %c\n", c);
                if (c == 'x') { break; }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I forgot: the signal being handled is blocked while being handled, so `raise` isn't called until after my handler returns, and the default behavior is enabled by the last line for everything...

Comment: `signal()` is not recommended, `man signal`: "*Avoid its
       use: use sigaction(2) instead.*"

Comment: @cdarke I think `sigaction` handlers also block the signal they are handling, so I think it is irrelevant to the question. But I do agree with you.

Comment: @GregSchmit No with `signal`, delivered signals are not blocked (at least this is not specified), this is one of the reason you should use `sigaction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blanked and forgot that a signal is blocked while it is being handled. Which means that `SIGINT` wouldnt' *actually* be raised until after the handler returns, and after I've set the action back from `SIG_DFL` to my custom handler. Therefore, it is looped.

A working handler for my example looks like:

```
static void handler(int sig) {
        if (sig == SIGCONT) {
                // do something interesting
                signal(sig, handler);
                signal(SIGTSTP, handler);
        } else {
                // do something else interesting
                signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
                raise(sig);
        }
}
```

Comment: That's just bizarre looking to me.  Why are you changing sig handlers in the middle of your sig handler?  And you're not tracking what the previous handler value is, so it seems you're going right off script for whatever implementation you have.

Comment: The idea is to engage in some action but then proceed with default behavior of the signal handler. `SIGCONT` and `SIGTSTP` are special cases since they might be called multiple times because they don't cause the program to exit.

Comment: @jwdonahue The original problem that this stems from is a piece of software that changes the `termios` settings. If someone hits `Ctrl-C`, I want to revert the `termios` changes, but then continue with the normal signal behavior (like exiting with code 130). But then I had problems with someone hitting `Ctrl-Z` and then `fg`. To handle that, I had to make sure I reregister my signal handler on `SIGCONT`, otherwise if they do it twice the `termios` settings would be off.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thanks! Yeah my issue was having to re-register handlers in the case of `Ctrl-Z` and `fg` (signals `SIGTSTP` and `SIGCONT`, respectively) otherwise things would only ever work the first time around.

Comment: So it sounds like you really need two signal handlers, one for each type. But I think you should chain your handlers.  Some static module initialization somewhere might have its own signal handlers as well.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yeah that's all great ideas -- I actually do get the previous_handler and run it rather than the default, but to strip out extraneous stuff I got rid of that in my demo.

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `signal()` is loosely defined — all sorts of implementations are valid implementations for either standard C or POSIX.  If you want controlled behaviour that's reliable across platforms, use `sigaction()` and not `signal()`.  In particular, signal blocking while a signal handler is in effect is not guaranteed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought that `signal`/`sigaction` were just different way of setting up the signal handler, and that either way, the signal would be blocked while the handler is running because the handler is independent of the mechanism used to register it. I believe you, but it seems to mean that I don't quite understand signal/sigaction if it can make the handling part behave so differently. Is it because of some flag variable that signal/sigaction control?

Comment: Yes, no, sort of.  Yes, they're two different ways of setting up the signal handling.  No, there's not much consistency between the different ways that `signal()` sets up signal handling on different systems.  The mess with `signal()` predates the C and POSIX standards. There were systems where the signal handler was reset to the default before the signal handler was called; others didn't. There were systems that blocked signals while signals were handled; others didn't. With `sigaction()`, you can control and simulate any of the archaic behaviours. The behaviour of `signal()` is not portable.